# How can I hide file extensions in the URL of my site with Apache?

Tags: apache, apache2

Before anyone says this is a duplicate - I tried all other similar questions without any successful results.

I use apache.

I am trying to hide file extensions in the URL. For example, index.php would show as index in the URL.

So what I did:

1) I created a .htaccess file, pasted this into it:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+?)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+?)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

2) Uploaded `.htacccess` to `www/html` folder

3) Restarted apache

4) Ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

5) Restarted apache again

6) Went to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and pasted this in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` tab:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

7) restarted apache

And... file extensions still show on my website. This is my first time playing around with .htaccess so can someone please explain what I am doing wrong and the steps I should take to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is break down the rules and apply them one at a time.
Remove everything in `.htaccess` and addthe below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now see if files with `.php` extension resolve correctly.
Then add the .html rule. It is exactly the same just change the extension.